# What is the best way to draw figures with canvas and set their angle?

Tags: java, android, graphics, custom-controls, rotation

I'm having a big trouble here. I need to draw a doll in a bed (as in a medical bed), and I can't seem to do it. I tried by creating a custom view, then I started to draw. I used `canvas.drawCircle` and `canvas.drawRect`. I managed to draw this doll, but I based it size on the height and width of the custom view, so in the end I couldn't set the angles.

Then, I tried to set my custom xml attribute (size), and then wrap its content. But wrap_content didn't work, it was always setting as full screen. So I couldn't use this too, because I need the right position of the head to set up the rest of the body.

What I exactly need is, draw some geometric forms, and then manipulate them individually. Like, the user choose to move the leg, then when he press the up button, the leg will set angle +1. I don't know if this is possible with a custom View and only onDraw. I'm really really really lost now, please, someone at least point me out what I need to use to achieve this.

[Picture](http://i42.tinypic.com/r859ol.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When drawing into the canvas, you are able to perform all kinds of transformations to the shapes you want to draw.

So if you first want to rotate the whole doll, you should perform a transformation before the doll is drawn. Then you can transform each body part within that trasformation.
For example, a doll with one leg.

```
//save the canvas transformation state
canvas.save();
   //first move the whole doll
   canvas.translate(dollPosition.x,dollposition.y);
   //we are now inside the coordinate system of the doll
   //draw head (Position is now relative to the center of the doll position)
   canvas.drawCircle(dollHeadPosition.x, dollHeadPosition.y, headRadius, paint);
   //save the canvas to transform leg independently
   canvas.save();
      canvas.translate(legPosition.x,legPosition.y);
      //draw leg
      canvas.drawRect(...);
      //restore the canvas to get back to your doll coordinate system
   canvas.restore()
//restore canvas to get to global coordinate system
canvas.restore()
```

There are all kinds of transformations, like rotation and skewing and so on. Just use your auto-completion to find out how they are written.

(I hope the indentation makes it clear, how it works)

Comment: Very nice, I managed to draw the whole doll and now its resizing properly, thanks to your post. But I still can't understand how I can rotate the doll. For example, I wanted to rotate the head and the body, but it rotates from right to left, not from left to right. How do I do this?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have a counter-clockwise rotation, but want it to be clock-wise? Then you can simply insert negative values for the rotation angle.
If I answered your Question, please accept my answer, and ask a new question for your new specific problem.

Answer (score 2):

Best way is to use [RenderScript](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html) or [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html)

It give you best performance but it`s hard to implement. [Here](http://blog.jayway.com/2009/12/03/opengl-es-tutorial-for-android-part-i/) is good tutorial, there are 5 chapters in detail.

Comment: That looks really good, but I think I need something simpler. I don't really need 3D. I need something simple, more of a 2D. It's just a stick figure to represent the angle. It's because when he press the UP button, the bed will actually go up. The simple doll is a reference to see if the bed is up or is it the body. I posted an image, please take a look at it.